# Does the Augmented Reality on Marvel trade paperbacks work properly?

Tags: marvel

I have the Captain Marvel trade paperback with a few Augmented Reality (AR) symbols on it. Sadly, it hasn't been working when I use the app. So my question is: does the Augmented Reality only work on single issues or is it just this specific trade paperback that doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but it's fiddly - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYfxQ0X7hx4

Answer (score 3):

I have an *Iron Man* hardcover collection that has the AR tags. It does work, but it's *incredibly* finicky.  I was only able to get the app to recognize the tag after a few minutes of fiddling with it.  I couldn't figure out any obvious reason it was failing; the book was in excellent even lighting, the page wasn't particularly curved. At some point, it just decided to work.

Keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

The app has to download everything first, which might take a while. You should be able to see which pages are available in the app menus. A WiFi connection is to be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Aurasma app. This is what the marvel app uses. Once you have the app subscribe to the marvel comics auras. Put in a search for marvel and each of the comics and click follow. The Aurasma app can be used to view the content where you see the ar symbol or if you have clicked follow the marvel ar app will now magically work. Less hastle by just using Aurasma instead. 
Let me know if this works for all of you too.